# How to breakdown the formula $(\hat{a}_1 + \hat{a}_2)^6$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, operator-theory, power-series

I can easily  breakdown the the power expansion I have mentioned  $(a_1 + a_2)^6$. The problem is that they are operator so I can not rearrange them in normal ways, it is because the order matters.

$$ a_1^6 + 6a_1^5 a_2 + 15 a_1^4 a_2^2 + 20 a_1^3a_2^3 + 15 a_1^2 a_2^4 + 6 a_1 a_2^5 + a_2^6 $$

the above expression could be right only if they weren't operators.

Do you have any good ways that I can break down the power series  without violating the order in a very convenient way?

Comment: It'll be helpful to know the $\hat{a}_{1}$ and $\hat{a}_{2}$ properties. It could lead to some simplification.

Comment: they are operator and they don't commute too.

Answer (score 0):

Take for example the second term. The $6 a_1^5 a_2$ comes from $\hat a_1^5\hat a_2+\hat a_1^4 \hat a_2 \hat a_1+\hat a_1^3 \hat a_2 \hat a_1^2+\hat a_1^2 \hat a_2 \hat a_1^3+\hat a_1 \hat a_2 \hat a_1^4+\hat a_2 \hat a_1^6$. You need to write all possible combinations.

Comment: for every term in the same way?

Comment: Yes. Think of having a 6 digit number, only made out of 1 and 2. There should be $2^6=64$ such numbers